# VS 2010: After installing WinPhone dev tools, can't choose solution platform

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, projects-and-solutions, toolbar

After installing VS2010, I can no longer choose the solution platform in the toolbar (x86/x64/AnyCPU/etc), even for non-Windows Phone projects. I can choose the platform manually by choosing "Configuration Manager" and doing it that way, but that's a bit annoying. In its place there's a greyed out "Windows Phone 7 Emulator" dropdown. Any ideas? Here's what my toolbar looks like right now:

[image]

### Solution

Matt Lacey's answer pointed me in the right direction. Go to customize, then choose the toolbars radio button, "Standard" in the combo box next to it, then (under the build category), add the solution platform and remove the deployment device. Sucks they do this automatically for all project types, but whatever.

Comment: For what it's worth I didn't have the same situation as you. When I added the phone SDK my copy of VS Ultimate added the deployment option without removing the platform option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize the toolbars however you want. Simply right click on the tool bar and select 'Customize...'. You can select what is displayed and where in the toolbars.